# Controller repeating in URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, wamp

I have a Controller called `Register` that looks like this:

```
class Register extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //set rules here

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            //everything checks out
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('register');
        }
    }
}
```

The view contains a form that posts to `register/create`.

My problem is, when I go to `localhost/register` and fill out the form incorrectly, the form reloads, but the url is now:

`localhost/register/register/create`

If I enter it incorrectly again

`localhost/register/register/register/create`

and so on...

I'm guess this is an `htaccess` and I've tried using some standard CodeIgniter htaccess files available online, but none fix this issue. I'm using this on a WAMP server.

**EDIT**

The view file only consists of the form, for now. I prefer using direct HTML instead of the CodeIgniter Form helper.

```
<form id="register_form" method="post" action="register/create" title="Create an Account">
    <!-- input fields -->
</form>
```

Comment: Please post your view file - specially the form open section - sounds like your action URL is wrong

Comment: @Ula, Laurencei : I've posted the view file above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use full url. Either `current_url()` or `site_url('register')` in your form's action.

It's good practice you use either of these or preffix with `base_url()` since that allows your site to run without having to be the domain path.
For instance you can, if needed run the site on example.com/my_site/ instead of only being able to run on example.com.

For fullest possible control of your form's action, always start on `http://` and avoid relative urls (action="register" for instance).

Comment: Hmm, let me try using an absolute path

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. That fixed the problem. I was also having the issue where form validation would work on `example.com/register` but not at `example.com/register/`. It fixed that issue as well.

Comment: @Ula: I find `form_open()` very unintuitive since this my first time using CI. Is there any advantage to using it over manually writing the form tag?

Comment: @xbonez from CI documentation: 
The main benefit of using this tag rather than hard coding your own HTML is that it permits your site to be more portable in the event your URLs ever change.

Comment: But if you use base_url(), current_url() or site_url() in the action="" it won't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Change the action parameter of your form from `register/create` to `/register/create`.  You're posting to a relative URL.  By adding the slash to the beginning of the action parameter you're making the URL absolute.  Therefore the form will always post to `http://domain-name/register/create`.

Comment: That indeed was the issue. I'm now using the CI `site_url` function to generate the absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I could address it by putting in my base_url the "http://" before my domain like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `base_url()`in your url :

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>/mypage">
```